# Subversion repository with multiple projects confuses Fisheye

Tags: svn, atlassian-fisheye

Is there a way to configure Fisheye so it will ignore all files except those in a specific directory tree in the Subversion repository? We have multiple projects in one Subversion repository. And Fisheye gladly offers up any and all files which have changed. Resulting in a difficult and confusing session when adding review content.

Answer (score 0):

A repository in FishEye does not need to match a SVN repository 1:1. Instead it is possible to create one or multiple repositories in FishEye that reference a specific directory tree within a SVN repository only. As explained in the [Atlassian FishEye documentation on SVN repository setup](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/subversion-298976887.html#Subversion-SVNrepositorysetup) one can specify both a *SVN URL* as well as a *Path* parameter at creation of a FishEye repository. By specifying different *pathes* it is possible to create a separate "repository" in FishEye for each of your projects within a the one Subversion repository.

Comment: To be honest, I am a user and our support team never figured this out.  We did setup multiple Fisheye accounts and pointed them 1 layer lower in the SVN repository so that we could setup reviews for 2 different projects in the same SVN repository.  But more than not, it appeared that either Fisheye was confused or the way our support team setup Fisheye was confusing to Fisheye.  Nothing work better then starting over with a new SVN repository and placing the project at the root of that SVN repository's directory structure.